# Sort excel data which is in short notations example 190B, 1.2K ,1.35M , 2.24B, 1000 How can I sort such data

Tags: excel

How to sort below data in excel in descending order

```
19.42B
86.40M
7.65B
6.09B
6.59B
1.2M
100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a helper column that converts the text to their equivalent number then sort both columns on that new column.

Use this formula to get the number equivalent:

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)*10^(MATCH(RIGHT(A1,1),{"K","M","B","T"},0)*3),A1)
```

[image]

Then sort on the new column:

[image]